# It should be set to 65000 to avoid operational disruption

Tags: rhel6, solr, ulimit

I'm following [Taking Solr to Production | Apache Solr Reference Guide 8.5](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/taking-solr-to-production.html), however unable to overcome warning while restarting `solr` service:

```
# service solr restart
*** [WARN] *** Your open file limit is currently 1024.
 It should be set to 65000 to avoid operational disruption.
 If you no longer wish to see this warning, set SOLR_ULIMIT_CHECKS to false in your profile or solr.in.sh
*** [WARN] ***  Your Max Processes Limit is currently 1024.
 It should be set to 65000 to avoid operational disruption.
 If you no longer wish to see this warning, set SOLR_ULIMIT_CHECKS to false in your profile or solr.in.sh
Sending stop command to Solr running on port 8983 ... waiting up to 180 seconds to allow Jetty process 16065 to stop gracefully.
Waiting up to 180 seconds to see Solr running on port 8983 [\]
Started Solr server on port 8983 (pid=16320). Happy searching!

#
```

My system:

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.10 (Santiago)
# uname -a
Linux X.X.X 2.6.32-754.30.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri May 29 04:45:43 EDT 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
#
```

after doing `man 5 limits.conf`:

```
# cat /etc/security/limits.d/498-solr.conf
solr    hard    nofile  65000
solr    hard    nproc   65000
#
```

however, I am still getting that warning message while restart of solr service.

Please advise)

Thanks in advance!

---

@MirceaVutcovici:

```
# grep 'Max processes' /proc/$(pgrep solr)/limits
grep: /proc//limits: No such file or directory
# pgrep solr
# echo $?
1
# ps ax | grep solr
 1926 ?        Sl     2:37 java -server -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=250 -XX:+UseLargePages -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -Xloggc:/var/solr/logs/solr_gc.log -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=9 -XX:GCLogFileSize=20M -Dsolr.jetty.inetaccess.includes= -Dsolr.jetty.inetaccess.excludes= -Dsolr.log.dir=/var/solr/logs -Djetty.port=8983 -DSTOP.PORT=7983 -DSTOP.KEY=solrrocks -Dhost=rlos.uftwf.local -Duser.timezone=UTC -Djetty.home=/opt/solr/server -Dsolr.solr.home=/var/solr/data -Dsolr.data.home= -Dsolr.install.dir=/opt/solr -Dsolr.default.confdir=/opt/solr/server/solr/configsets/_default/conf -Dlog4j.configurationFile=/var/solr/log4j2.xml -Xss256k -Dsolr.jetty.https.port=8983 -Dsolr.log.muteconsole -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=/opt/solr/bin/oom_solr.sh 8983 /var/solr/logs -jar start.jar --module=http
 9029 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep solr
# grep 'Max processes' /proc/1926/limits
Max processes             1024                 65000                processes
#
```

Comment: You can see that the limits you configured in /etc/security/limits.d/498-solr.conf file are applied to the process by running: `grep 'Max processes' /proc/$(pgrep solr)/limits` Please attach the output to the question.

Comment: @MirceaVutcovici output is attached to the question and yes I see that limits were *NOT* applied (hence the warning), would you happened to know the right way to apply?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You set the `hard` limits, but not the `soft` limits, and the `soft` limits are what is being reported. You should also set the `soft` limits, in the same way.

```
solr    soft    nofile  65000
solr    soft    nproc   65000
```

(The app itself should be able to raise the limits, up to the `hard` limit, but apparently the developers haven't chosen to do this.)

Comment: That did the trick for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For some reason this solution didn't work for me. the solution was to change the file `/etc/systemd/system.conf` by adding the following lines.

```
DefaultLimitNOFILE=65000
DefaultLimitNPROC=65000
```

after that, run `systemctl daemon-reload`.

Checking the settings:

```
~ # systemctl show | egrep "NOFILE|NPROC"
DefaultLimitNOFILE=65000
DefaultLimitNOFILESoft=65000
DefaultLimitNPROC=65000
DefaultLimitNPROCSoft=65000
```